# Java Reading String to Float as Input from File through Command Line

Tags: java, input, runtime-error

I have to read Strings from a file which the first `String` is N then convert it as a `Integer` for a cycle `for` to go from 0 to N, reading each time another String from file and then convert each line read as a `float`as following:

`FILE Name: test.txt` with the following content:

`4
1.21
1.31
1.21
1.32`

`Java Code`

```
public class lpa2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        String line;int n;
        while((line = nextLine())!=null){
            n = Integer.parseInt(line);
            float v[] = new float[n];
            for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
                String temp = readln();
                v[i] = Float.parseFloat(temp);
            }
            for(float f:v)
               System.out.println(f);
        }



       }
  public static String readln() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        return bi.readLine();

    }

 }
```

When i use command line like this:

```
javac -nowarn lpa2.java
```

then

```
java lpa2 < test.txt
```

to use file as input i get the following error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf370"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at lpa2.main(lpa2.java:15)
```

While if i try to do it using eclipse it works perfectly ....

How can i fix this? i used readln() that i created instead Scanner because i needed a faster input reader and even if i try using Scanner i get the same error ... Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks ...

Comment: How do you run it in eclipse?

Comment: just run the program and put the numbers in one by one ...

Comment: Can you confirm the `test.txt` file that you are referring to is actually in the directory you launched the `java` program in? Are you sure it's not some other file with the same name that contains some other text?

Answer (score 1):

Your file "test.txt" is saved as a rtf file -- I am guessing you saved it from Word or similar word processors? If you open the file in a text editor (e.g., notepad) you'll find that it doesn't contain what you expect.

Comment: thats not the problem... since this is even the same error it gives in a Programming contest evaluator ... tried both extensions and it gives the same error.

Comment: @exceltior This has nothing to do with extensions. It has to do with file content. Open the file with a text editor like notepad or gedit.

Comment: @Sotirios like i said thats not the problem ... i edited with gedit and gave same problem ... found a new way to read the input and work just fine ...thanks anyway

Comment: @exceltior Explain to me where the value `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf370` comes from?

Comment: @sotirios after i edited like you said the error is this:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
 at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
 at lpa2.main(lpa2.java:16) `

Like you can see thats not the problem ...

Comment: @exceltior That's a completely different exception thrown because you are passing `null` to your `parseFloat()` call. That is happening because your `bi.readLine()` is returning `null` (or something similar, I can't tell from the code you posted).